# Can we add DLL files into an specific folder programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly

I have a simple asp.net project(demo). When I build a project the dlls will get added into the bin folder, and when we run the application I have to add those dlls into my customized folder called `mybin`, I don't want to use file copy paste solution(means Directory's method of GetFile and all).

I want it to add those dlls again into my custom folder programmatically.

Comment: @JohnB actually i am not getting from where to start. that code i will write in any of the normal method for testing purpose as of now. But i am not getting how to load those dll using c# code.

Comment: More importantly, what problem are you trying to solve?  Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @Moo-Juice its used to merge some other third party application but as of now I don't need to add any application now i just have to do what i have mention above.

Comment: @TauFeeQ I think you're going to have to elaborate a bit more (with an edit to the question), as I'm still not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @TauFeeQ - How about in you project added a new folder and place those dlls inside this folder. Then set the 'Copy to OutPut Directory' as 'Copy Always'. But in this case also your entire custom folder will be inside the bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [post-build events in your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2019#specify-a-build-event) to move the files?